# FactoryBot: Trait not registered: "todo_id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've been working through a [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one) that introduced factory bot in order to help with the testing. The tutorial has been otherwise great, but I haven't been able to resolve a means to fixing this error:

```
Failure/Error: let!(:items) { create_list(:item, 20, todo_id: todo.id) }

      KeyError:
        Trait not registered: "todo_id"
```

items_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe 'Items API' do
  # Initialize the test data
  let!(:todo) { create(:todo) }
  let!(:items) { create_list(:item, 20, todo_id: todo.id) }
  let(:todo_id) { todo.id }
  let(:id) { items.first.id }
...
```

FB items.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    name { Faker::StarWars.character }
    done { false }
    todo_id nil
  end
end
```

FB todos.rb

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :todo do
    title { Faker::Lorem.word }
    created_by { Faker::Number.number(digits: 10) }
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :todos do
    resources :items
  end
end
```

**Migrations**

Todos have many Items

```
class CreateTodos < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :todos do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :created_by

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.boolean :done
      t.references :todo, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I imagine it's a relatively simple fix, but I am new to factory bots and I'm hesitant to follow some possible solutions because they change a lot of stuff. If anyone has a solution, i'd love to know otherwise I'm going to keep trying to dig around factorybot docs, which isnt the worst thing.

Comment: How does the migration of todos look like?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Added the migrations for Todos and Items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's possible to set up associations within factories. If the factory
>   name is the same as the association name, the factory name can be left
>   out.
>   - [FactoryBot Readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md)

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    name { Faker::Lorem.character }
    done { false }
    todo
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

As todo_id is the foreign key that creates a relationship between an item and a todo you shouldn't assign it manually, because when running your test suite you don't know what's the id of that todo - of course you can reset your DB every time you run your tests or pass a seed, but that doesn't cover the 100% of the cases.

You can make use of the [associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) FactoryBot provides.

As the association can be inferred from the model, you can do:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    todo
    name { Faker::Lorem.character }
    done { false }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! That's why I felt it was really wrong.. the association should handle it but, until your post ( and max's ) I wasnt really sure how to set that up in the fb environment.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the issue was coming from here:

**items.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    name { Faker::Starwars.character }
    done { false }
    todo_id nil
  end
end
```

I changed it to:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    name { Faker::Lorem.character }
    done { false }
    todo_id { 1 }
  end
end
```

It's Lorem and not Starwars because I got this error:
`uninitialized constant Faker::StarWars`

I gave the `todo_id` a value of 1, this *feels* wrong. But until I find a better solution ... it's passing the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify association like this

```
association :todo, factory: :todo
```